# Pasted the same uv coords onto multiple faces, but some of them are fliped

Tags: texturing, uv

So, im trying to paste the same uv coordinates onto multiple faces so they tile nicely,
but every time i do it some of them end up in the wrong direction.
Can anyone please explain why this happens?
I've tried everything, but the only solution i found is to flip every wrong face manually,
but it takes ages.[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the "flips" completely random, or does it apply to each and every tile and is "flipped" by a constant amount?

Comment: Yeah, the direction each face flips the uv is consistent every time, like, even if i paste the coords again, the pattern stays the same.

Comment: That's good to know that the flipping is consistent. In that case, you can simply add a *Mapping node* between the *Texture Coordinate Node* and whatever's on the other side. Now, just screw around with the *Rotation* until it corrects the flipping

Answer (score 1):

- In Edit Mode, press U then click on Reset.

[image]

---

[image]

- In the UV Editor, scale all the reset UV's to the correct place on the image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but, the thing is, the pattern stays the same even if i reset the uv on every face.

Comment: Can you explain what you have done so far to get to where you are? Or if you don't mind sharing, can you upload your blend file after packing external data (File>External Data>Pack External Data) to https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sure thing, i didn't know you could post blend files.

Comment: I have no idea why it's doing that but un-Subdividing and Subdividing fixes it.